# Installing Cairo in DevC++

Tags: c++, cairo, dev-c++

I wanted to play around with postscript output form my c++ programs and found the Cairo package while searching for a library to help me. I am using Dev-Cpp and i downloaded Cairo via its package management system. The installation went ok. I can't compile yet because I get "cairo.h - no such file in directory"
I know i still have to manage some includes and linker parameters, but I cant find a tutorial anywhere.
Can anyone please tell me how to make it run?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Which operating system you're using? I assume some flavor of linux, since windows doesn't have 'package management system'.

A possible problem is that you didn't install *development* package. On ubuntu, for example, you need to install `libcairo2-dev`.

Another possible problem could be that you didn't add the cairo header directory to your include path. On linux, the easiest way to do this is to compile your file as follows:

```
g++ $(pkg-config --cflags cairo) your_file.cc
```

By the way, why don't you use `cairomm`? This is quite nice C++ wrapper around C APIs.

Comment: I am using windows. I meant the built in package manager Dev-C++ has.